# Track folder using php and inotify

Tags: php, php-5.5, inotify

I need help to understand how i can make inotify work with PHP. 
I have a main file where i call a instance of a inotify class i created.

This works for 30 seconds and then php throws a timeout  error. In that time window it can in fact print information from new files and deleted ones. It kinda works but...

My questions for you guys are:

1. how can i make it persistent and stable. I mean i can set timeout requests for unlimited time but that doesn't seem to be a good practice. How to deal with this?
2. It's supposed to work like this? I call the function and the php
   hangs in that loop until a new change happens?

My index.php

`$teste = new Inotify_service();`

```
$teste->add_watch('files');
```

---

```
class Inotify_service
{
    private $instance;  
    private $watch_id;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->instance = inotify_init();
        stream_set_blocking($this->instance, 0); # this is needed so inotify_read while operate in non blocking mode
    }

    /**
     * [add_watch Adds a new watch or modify an existing watch for the file or directory specified in pathname]
     * @param [string] $pathname [description]
     */
    public function add_watch($pathname)
    {
        $this->watch_id = inotify_add_watch($this->instance, $pathname, IN_CREATE | IN_DELETE);

        while(true){

            // read events 
            $events = inotify_read($this->instance);

            // if the event is happening within our 'Files directory'
            if ($events[0]['wd'] === $this->watch_id){
                // a file was created
                if($events[0]['mask'] === IN_CREATE){
                printf("Created file: %s in Files directory\n", $events[0]['name']);
                // a file was deleted
                } else if ($events[0]['mask'] === IN_DELETE){
                    printf("Deleted file: %s in Files directory\n", $events[0]['name']);
                }                   
            }
        }

        // stop watching our directories
        inotify_rm_watch($this->instance, $this->watch_id);
        // close our inotify instance
        fclose($this->instance);
    }
```

Comment: The php script should be set with an unlimited timeout and executed from the `php-cli`  and **not** through Apache.

Comment: I understand. And i guess i should only change unlimited timeout for cli php.ini file. Once a file change is found the current watch is deleted? I need to reset again the watch?

Comment: You can actually set the timeout directly in the file at the top of it so you don't have to change global configurations (given that, of course, you can modify php.ini values form within your files). This is of course environment specific. The watcher should not be deleted on file change, it should persist through file changes. Otherwise you would pin the box spawning new instances of the watcher.

Comment: Great tip yes, i will do that. Memory and Processor are fine with this?

Comment: That's actually a tough answer to be honest with you, and after looking at your code one more time, I would say that given your environment perhaps you do want the watcher to end each time a file changes, my apologies for not being more clear about that initially. I had made some assumptions when quickly looking at the code that I shouldn't have. Sorry for that.

Comment: No worries, in fact that was my mistake, the code is just a demo.I don't have intention to end the watch. I am trying to figure how to deal with a ftp folder where files will be stored and needed to be parsed and information stored in a database all the time. Is this php extension a good solution in your opinion?

Comment: I think `Good` is subjective here. Is it good enough to do what you need to do? Yes. Is there another way you could do it? Probably. Would that way be better than the way you're doing it? Hard to say. I would implement your solution now and observe to identify if there are any drawbacks. If the drawbacks are too large, then I would suppose that finding an alternative would be a high priority.

Comment: Good response. I will try and see if it holds up! Thank you